# Removing extra screen on TouchWiz launcher

Tags: home-screen, samsung-touchwiz

I have a Samsung Galaxy Core Prime (SM-S820L) on Android 4.4.4, and I'm using TouchWiz launcher.

How do I remove the extra home screens?

Comment: Which launcher are you using? Have you tried anything so far to remove those home screens? List them, so that we avoid suggesting same solutions.

Comment: I am not sure what a launcher is, but I have a Android based phone. I have tried removing the widgets and keeping fingers on screen to bring up trashcan.  The page won't go in the can

Comment: Touchwiz..I goggled launcher after sending above info.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these instructions:

1. Tap the home button to make sure you're on the home screen
2. Use the pinch gesture (as if zooming out - fingers move toward one another)
3. Tap and hold the page to be removed
4. Drag the page to the X at the top of the screen (see image)

   <sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

   [image: IMG: TouchWiz]

Source: [Pro tip: Remove unnecessary pages on your Android home screen](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-remove-unnecessary-pages-on-your-android-home-screen/)